# Splitting text file into multiline records using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex, multiline

I would like to separate my text into a list of records using the timestamp as the separator.  My current code captures the first record, but not the second.  How should I modify my code to capture both?

```
s = """13:45:09 HEY HOW ARE YOU

     I AM FINE

13:50:10 OK THEN

     Bye"""

import re

text_regex = r'^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(.*?)(?=\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)'
pattern = re.compile(text_regex,re.DOTALL)

records = []

for match in pattern.findall(s):
    match = match.rstrip()
    records.append(match)
```

Comment: Probably, just use `records = re.split(r'(?!\A)(?=^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)', s, re.M)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/UwXc4i/1)).

Answer (score 0):

> My current code captures the first record, but not the second. How should I modify my code to capture both?

Your code doesn't capture the second record because due to the trailing `(?=\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)` lookahead it matches only if a timestamp follows, which isn't so for the last record.
Wiktor Stribiżew's suggestion works if corrected to

```
records = re.split(r'(?!\A)(?=^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)', s, flags=re.M)
```

- otherwise the *multiline* flag would be taken for the third positional argument *maxsplit*.

A slightly simplified variant of Wiktor Stribiżew's suggestion which drops extra text before the first timestamp:

```
records = re.split(r'(?=\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)', s)[1:]
```

Another variant which (as in your original code) doesn't capture the timestamps:

```
records = re.split(r'\d\d:\d\d:\d\d', s)[1:]
```

Comment: I admit I [missed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618171/splitting-text-file-into-multiline-records-using-regex/66618638#comment117764260_66618171) `flags=` in my comment. Still, this will not work if the data is not at the start of the string, and this part is always not clear when the example text is so "generic".

Comment: You are right; it's often questionable whether the example is representative of the real data. I added some variants of your solution.